# How to rid my People tile of the Facebook "f"?

Tags: facebook, people-hub

This is such a tiny thing, but it's still a little annoying.

Since going over to a new WP7 handset I've had Facebook's "f" logo inside my People tile like so:

[image]

It was never there in my old WP7 handset and I've got no Facebook account linked up to my phone/People hub (just Hotmail, Google, Twitter).

It's taking up 1⁄9 of my People tile and masquerading as family/friend and I want rid. Seems it must be a setting, because as I say, it wasn't there in my old handset.

Comment: really really dumb question, but are you sure you don't have facebook linked? :)

Comment: "linked", how/what does that mean? Under People Hub -> Settings the accounts listed are Windows Live, Twitter, Google

Comment: two more questions :)  1) is it always there, or does it flip out for another picture? 2) is it possible a contact has that image set for his profile picture?

Comment: Have you tried (re)pinning the tile?

Comment: I went down to the Microsoft store, and looked at several phones. a few had this and some didn't. Maybe it has to do with how many contacts you have?

Answer (score 2):

This comes up even if you haven't set up *any* accounts, and appears to have been introduced with Windows Phone v7.5.

when you first go into the people hub, it will prompt to integrate with Facebook, and choosing "not now" does seem to stop the "f" coming up. If you do choose to synchronise with Facebook, then bets are off, and it **will** come up.

Comment: Recently I did a factory reset on my Focus. Even before set any account that "f" was already there.

Comment: I tested with a brand new retail phone, and saw that the f appears *until* you explicitly decline to set up facebook integration (or defer to later, as they prefer to call it ;)

Comment: @RowlandShaw when do you get that choice? I recently did a full reset on the phone and I haven't been asked about faceboook. "f" still in my hub.